# Showing that function are equal almost everywhere in Sobolev Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces, holder-spaces

Consider the Holder space $C^{0,1-\frac{n}{p}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and the Sobolev Space $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Take $u_{m} \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that Morrey's Inequality we have $||u_{m}||_{C^{0,1-\frac{n}{p}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})} \leq C||u_{m}||_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}$. We are also given that $u_{m} \rightarrow \bar{u}$ in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $u_{m} \rightarrow u^{*}$ in $C^{0,1-\frac{n}{p}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

How does it follow that $u^{*} = u \text{ a.e}$? What result is used?

Thanks for assistance. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $u_m \to u^*$ in $C^{0,1-\frac np}$ you know that $u_m(x) \to u^*(x)$ for all $x$. On the other hand, since $u_m \to u$ in $W^{1,p}$ (and in particular in $L^p$) there is a subsequence with the property that $u_{m_j}(x) \to \bar u(x)$ almost everywhere. Since $u_{m_j}(x) \to u^*(x)$ for all $x$, you get a.e. equality.

Comment: How does Holder convergence imply point-wise convergence?

Comment: Is the following fine: Holder Space convergence implies uniform convergence which implies point-wise convergence. $L^{p}$ convergence does not imply point-wise convergence but guarantees the existence of a sub-sequence that converges point-wise (is there a text where I can find this proof?) Then we have two sub-sequences converging pointwise in $(\mathbb{R},| \text{ }|)$: $u_{m_{j}} \rightarrow u^{*}(x)$ for all $x$ and we have $u_{m_{j}}(x) \rightarrow \bar{u}(x) \text{ a.e }$. It follows by convergent sequences that $\bar{u} = u^{*} \text{ a.e }$.

Comment: Holder convergence implies pointwise convergence follows simply from the observation that $|u_{m}(x) - u^{*}(x)| <= \text{sup}|u_{m}(x) - u^{*}(x)|$. It then seems as thought it does also imply uniform convergence?